# How can I call forceUpdate on the root element in React?

Tags: reactjs, components

I need to call forceUpdate on the app root of my React App or on another component than the one I am currently in.  I know to call forceUpdate on the current component it is `this.forceUpdate()`, but how would I call it on another component?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `this.forceUpdate()` function vis props to a child component

**root.js**

```
var Root = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <UpdateComponent
        rootUpdate={this.forceUpdate.bind(this)}
      />
    );
  }
});
```

Then you can access call `this.props.rootUpdate()` in your UpdateComponent whenever you need the root to be force updated.

Answer (score 0):

`forceUpdate` is a worse case scenario and should be avoided because it deviates from the React way of doing things.

> Normally you should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate() and only read from this.props and this.state in render(). This makes your component "pure" and your application much simpler and more efficient.

Changing the key of the element you want re-rendered will work. Set the key prop on your element via state and then when you want to update set state to have a new key.

```
<Element key={this.state.key} />
```

Then a change occurs and you reset the key

```
this.setState({ key: Math.random() });
```

I want to note that this will replace the element that the key is changing on. It is always discourage to use the forceUpdate as there is always a way to avaoid this.